# Volley JsonObjectRequest responses are not in order

Tags: android, android-volley, android-json

When i try to add multiple JsonObjectRequest in a queue then i added its responses response into an Array list now the problem is that the responses are not in same order i raised request it is stored randomly in Array list. So i couldn't able to identify responses of urls because it is random.

Example;

Request[1,2,3,4]

Response[2,1,4,3]

Any solution ? Thanks in advance.

MainClass

```
public class Maker extends Fragment implements Response.Listener, Response.ErrorListener {

    private String[] urls = {Declaration.Url1, Declaration.Url2, Declaration.Url3};
    private ArrayList<String> mResponces = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        for (String url : urls) {
            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, this, this);
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.d("onErrorResponse", error.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Object response) {
        mResponces.add(response.toString().trim());
        if (mResponces != null && mResponces.size() == urls.length) {
            PopulateData();
        }
    }

    private void PopulateData() {
        // The problem is the response are not in order
        String ResponceFormUrl1 = mResponces.get(0);
        String ResponceFormUrl2 = mResponces.get(1);
        String ResponceFormUrl3 = mResponces.get(2);
    }
}
```

AppController

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find any answer to this ? i am stuck with the same problem

Comment: Yes, I found it, Created new Response class implemented Response.Listener and passed the current position of the for loop in its constructor during a request.

Comment: But wont that slow down the process.. I mean if I were downloading many images but i want them in particular order then the method which you are telling will make them sequential. Please correct me if I am wrong. Also can u plz provide the code sample by how you fixed it. Thanks in advance.